# Posicionamento de imagem

Tags: html, css

Estou com um problema no posicionamento de imagens em um site que estou desenvolvendo.
Algumas delas aparentemente não estão se encaixando em uma linha, no caso, posicionei 4 por linha.
Fiz algumas tentativas, criei um div que acomodou todo o conteúdo da imagem, ficando assim:

```
  <div class="posicao">
    <div class="produtos-wrapper">
      <div class="produtos-conteudo one-fourth"> 
          <a href="detalhes.php?produto=<?php echo $row_rsProdutos['id_produto']; ?>&dep=<?php echo $row_rsProdutos['id_departamento']; ?>&subdep=<?php echo $row_rsProdutos['id_subdepartamento']; ?>"><img class="photo" src="<?php echo $foto; ?>"  /></a>
            <div class="content">
              <h3 class="name"><?php echo $row_rsProdutos['descricao'];  ?> </h3>
              <span class="job-title"> <?php echo $row_rsProdutos['codigo_msb']; ?> </span> </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <?php } while ($row_rsProdutos = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsProdutos)); ?>              
    </div>
```

E o css, assim:

```
.posicao {
float: right;
width:auto;     
}
```

Mas as imagens ainda ficam com o espaços.
O site para verificação é esse [Site para exibição](http://www.moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você trabalha com div, basicamente você tem vários quadrados de sustentação para inserção de conteúdo, sendo ele texto ou multimídia. No caso, esta havendo uma falta de padronização de altura e por isso as divs não encaixam.

Acrescente isso no CSS:

```
.produtos-conteudo{
height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @Rafael Barbosa, excelente dica.

Comment: @adventistapr Disponha! Funcionou então?

Comment: Sim, perfeitamente.

Comment: @adventistapr Que bom! Fico feliz! Por gentileza, se você puder marcar como pergunta certa para orientar outros usuários que possam estar com dúvidas em algo parecido, eu agradeceria.